# I need to bulk convert a number of PDFs in a folder to plaintext

Tags: import, pdf-format

I have 159 PDF in a folder with nothing else in it. I need them all converted to raw text. I found the documentation for doing them one at a time, which worked. To do them in bulk I tried this

```
    Export[(C : \\ filepath \\ #.txt) & /@ Range[159], 
  Import["C:\\filepath\\*.pdf", "Plaintext"], "TEXT"];
```

which did not work. I can deal with the converted files as just separately numbered but if the original PDF filename survived as the name for the .txt file that would be better.

@Syed - Just figured out your hint. This worked perfectly!!

```
Export[StringJoin[
 "C:\\path\\pltxt", 
 ToString[#], ".txt"], ptVers[[#]], "TEXT"] & /@ Range[160];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a folder `pdftest` inside my `Documents` folder and put three pdf files there with one line of text each to create a MWE.

[image]

```
files = FileNames["pdftest/*.pdf"]
```

> ```
> {"pdftest\\I am file no 1.pdf", "pdftest\\I am file no 2.pdf", \
> "pdftest\\I am file no 3.pdf"}
> ```

```
Import[#, "Plaintext"] & /@ files
```

> {"I am file no 1 ", "I am file no 2 ", "I am file no 3 "}

From here, you can choose to `StringJoin` the individual items in the list or use as required.